# Occasionally get "attempt to apply non-function" error when applying getForm

Tags: api, r

I'm using getForm to repeatedly pull data from an api.  Sometimes the program finishes, and other times after some amount of iterations, I get the following error message:

```
Error in curlPerform(url = url, curl = curl, .opts = .opts) : 
attempt to apply non-function
In addition: There were more than 50 warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> traceback()
5: .Call("R_curl_easy_perform", curl, .opts, isProtected, .encoding, 
   PACKAGE = "RCurl")
4: curlPerform(url = url, curl = curl, .opts = .opts)
3: getURLContent(uri, .opts = .opts, .encoding = .encoding, binary = binary, 
   curl = curl)
2: getForm("https://xx", .params = parval)
1: fromJSON(getForm("https://xx", 
   .params = parval)) at #32
```

the warnings are:

```
In RCurlIconv(str, from = "C99", to = encoding) :
UTF-8 not supported iconv entries
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a download error, sometimes the download fails.  I just put in a provision to try the download again in that case.